# Tabs not aligned correctly

Tags: material-ui

I have created two tabs inside a Paper element, but instead of them being correctly aligned, the SCORE tab is too far to the right. Not sure why they are not auto adjusting the tab width to fit the width of the Paper element.

What am I doing wrong?

```
                <Paper
                  className={classes.paperTagsSection}
                >
                  <Box>
                    <Tabs
                      indicatorColor="primary"
                      textColor="primary"
                    >
                      <Tab label="Tags" />
                      <Tab label="Score" />
                    </Tabs>
                  </Box>
               </Paper>
```

[image: Tabs not aligned]

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. This worked:

```
                    <Tabs
                      indicatorColor="primary"
                      textColor="primary"
                    >
                      <Tab label="Tags" style={{ minWidth: '50%' }} />
                      <Tab label="Score" style={{ minWidth: '50%' }} />
                    </Tabs>
```